# googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo returns null value

Tags: api, migration, google-plus, google-signin

the below URLs I have been using for google sign in my website.

**log in URL**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope='.urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email') . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL) . '&response_type=code&client_id=' . CLIENT_ID . '&access_type=online
```

**access token URL**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

**UserInfo endpoint URL(new URL)**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo (returns null values)
```

**Google+ endpoint URL that I'm currently using**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me (returns email, names, etc)
```

I want to get user name & email to save in my DB. 
how can I get name & email with UserInfo endpoint URL which I have mentioned above?

**UPDATED:**

***I've changed my userinfo endpoint as 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me' and now it's working well***

Comment: Please format your question to look nice if you wanna someone to help you.!

Comment: did you send the access token to the userinfo endpoint?  Email will only be returned by the userinfo endpoint if you requested the email scope.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code that illustrates how you are using the UserInfo endpoint? Are the other endpoints working?

Comment: this is the reference url for my code http://usefulangle.com/post/9/google-login-api-with-php-curl @Prisoner

Comment: @DaImTo Sign in happening . there is no problem in that. i could not able to get the user's email and name using this URL. https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo. it is returning null value. meanwhile i can able to get the same from https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me. but i don't know whether this url will work after mar 7 2019

Comment: What exactly is the userinfo endpoint returning to you?   As for that endpoint know one knows if it will continue to work or not.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample code you linked to, there are at least a couple of changes you need to make or try.

The first is that you may need to request different scopes, since the scopes determine what will be returned. That code relies on scopes that will be invalid or no longer suggested. The [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#consentpageexperience) you should be using to get the profile and email are:

- openid
- profile
- email

(The longer scope names you use *should* also work, but you may want to try these simpler ones as well.)

So the `login_url` in step 2 might look more like this:

```
$login_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=' . urlencode('openid profile email') . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL) . '&response_type=code&client_id=' . CLIENT_ID . '&access_type=online';
```

Although the userinfo v2 endpoint is still semi-maintained, it has been deprecated.
Instead, try one of the following:

- The userinfo v3 endpoint at `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`
- Get the [discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery) at https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration and using the url associated with the `userinfo_endpoint` value.

There are still some things to pay attention to, however:

- Not all the data may be available. If the user has not set some profile information, the API can't provide it.
- The fields will not be the same as in the Plus endpoint. So while the data may be there, it may be in a different location in the object returned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but it does not work for me. Now it's working after changing userinfo endpoint to 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me'

Answer (score 0):

> access token URL `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` (returns null values)

You should provide valid credentials to get a response from [these openid endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo)

either by [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header or QueryParams; for instance:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=FOO_BAR...
```

> Either `access_token`, `id_token`, or `token_handle`

also applies to `v3` (`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`)